# Changing the side of the the master view controller to the right side in UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

is it possible to change the master view controllers side to the right hand side? Tried finding information on this couldn't find anything. Seems odd if you can't do it for people who are left handed etc.